# why there are differences between those two codes?

Tags: python

i wrote 2 simple codes in python that should make the same work, but it doesnt.
if you can tell me why is this, and also explain me more about the "everything is an object in python". thanks :)

```
def f(p=[]):
    print p
    f.a += 1
    print id(p)
    if(f.a == 1):
        p = p + [4]
    else:
        p = p + [5]
    return p
f.a = 0
f()
f()
f()
```

answer:

> ```
> []
> 40564496
> []
> 40564496
> []
> 40564496
> ```

```
def f(p=[]):
    print p
    f.a += 1
    print id(p)
    if(f.a == 1):
        p += [4]
    else:
        p +=[5]
    return p
#print f()
#print f()
f.a = 0
f()
f()
f()
```

answer:

> ```
> []
> 40892176
> [4]
> 40892176
> [4, 5]
> 40892176
> ```

like you see - the first code every time does a new list, and the second add to the last used one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never* pass a **mutable** object as a default value in python function as there will be **just one**. Consequently your second function always uses the same list, that was instationed during function creation. First one, on the other hand creates new lists during `p = p + [4]` assignments, thus there is no mutation of the default arg. Code this this way:

```
def f(p=None):
    if p is None:
        p = []

    print p
    f.a += 1
    print id(p)
    if(f.a == 1):
        p += [4]
    else:
        p +=[5]
    return p
```

`*` by never I mean "unless you really know what you are doing". There is always an exception from the rule, but if you need to pass a mutable as a default value, you need to understand its consequences very well, thus you would probably not be reading this answer anyway. In particular, it is discouraged in many Python style guides, such as [Google python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Default_Argument_Values)

> Do not use mutable objects as default values in the function or method definition.

This should also cause pylint warning W0102

> **dangerous-default-value (W0102):**
>       Dangerous default value %s as argument Used when a mutable value as list or dictionary is detected in a default value for an argument.

Comment: It's not that you should **never** pass mutable objects as default values, rather, you should understand what it means.

Comment: @juanpa - sure, there is always an exception (see updated answer).

Comment: I would not say, "*never* pass [a] mutable object as a default value." There are certain instances when such behavior is desired and useful (i.e. writing a memoization decorator).

Answer (score 1):

The operators `obj += other` and `obj = obj + other` are not the same. The previous often uses *inplace* modification, whereas the later usually creates a new object. In the case of lists, `obj += other` is the same as `obj.extend(other)`.

The second important thing is that `def` statements are only evaluated *once per scope*. If you define a function at module scope, `def` is evaluated once - that includes the creation of its default parameters!

```
def foo(bar=[]):
  print(id(bar))
```

In this case, bar will always default to the *same* list object that has been created when `def foo` was first evaluated.
Whenever you modify the default value, it will carry over to the next time this default is used.
Contrast this with:

```
def foo(bar=None):
  bar = bar if bar is not None else []
  print(id(bar))
```

In this case, the default list is *recreated* every time the function is called.